# Visa to visit the UK for Russian wife of a British citizen (French resident)

Tags: visas, uk

I am a British citizen living in France with my Russian wife who has a *carte de séjour* in France. Can we visit the UK without my wife getting a visa?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should be able to visit the UK together without visa, at least if your wife has an [article 10 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card), which would usually be the case in this situation (in French, this is called a *[carte de séjour mention membre de la famille d'un citoyen de l'Union](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F19315)*).

Answer (score 1):

I too am a British citizen living in France with my Russian wife who has a Carte de Séjour.
Have a look at the following link.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

I would recommend writing to or calling UK Visas and Immigration to be sure.

Comment: And while the link with the few lines might answer three different questions, it is better to write a real answer to each, not a copy. This answer, (to all three questions) runs a risk to be deleted as not an answer, even though there is a link in it.